# How read data from SQL Server database as a stream?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stream

I have 2 functions :

```
public T Load(string iFilePath)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(iFilePath))
    {
        return Load(file);
    }
}

public T Load(Stream inputStream)
{
    int mSize = 0;
    int mLength=0;
    var list = XmlProfilePersister.Load<string>(inputStream, out mSize, out mLength);
    ...
}
```

It reads file. How can I read this stream from a SQL Server database table: xml or other?

I.e. I want to upload the xml file to a table and avoid any files in my code.

Comment: Use a command lijne utility which is much more efficient than in c# (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).  I recommend sqlcmd.exe which is also built into PowerShell and you probably can achieve what you want in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanx, but I need it in my c# code.

Comment: You can do one of two ways 1) Use PowerShell class in c# 2) Run sqlcmd.exe from a Process Class.  Both ways will run much quicker than from doing query in c# and you do not need the intermediate stream.

Comment: you mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstream?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes, something like this

Comment: @jweng C# can stream also, as shown in the answer

Answer (score 0):

NET Framework 4.5 has a new feature
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support